# Change div height on button click

Tags: javascript, html

What I do wrong? Why div height didn't change?

```
<html>
  <head>    
  </head>

<body >
    <button type="button" onClick = "document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = 200px">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color:#E8EDF2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should get familiar with jquery, it makes things way easier. :) www.jquery.com

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just a silly mistake use quote('') in `'200px'`

```
 <html>
  <head>    
  </head>

<body >
    <button type="button" onClick = "document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = '200px';">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color:#E8EDF2"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 13):

Do this:

```
function changeHeight() {
document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = "200px"
}
<button type="button" onClick="changeHeight();"> Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at to vwphillips' post from 03-06-2010, 03:35 PM in
http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-190887.html

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

      <script type="text/javascript">

        function Div(id,ud) {
           var div=document.getElementById(id);
           var h=parseInt(div.style.height)+ud;
           if (h>=1){
              div.style.height = h + "em"; // I'm using "em" instead of "px", but you can use px like measure...
           }
        }
      </script>

   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <input type="button" value="+" onclick="Div('my_div', 1);">&nbsp;&nbsp; 
         <input type="button" value="-" onclick="Div('my_div', -1);"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="my_div" style="height: 1em; width: 1em; overflow: auto;"></div>

   </body>
</html>
```

This worked for me :)

Best regards!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set height as a string value when you use pixels.

```
document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = "200px"
```

Also try adding a DOCTYPE to your HTML for Internet Explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot the quotes. Change your code according to this:

```
    <button type="button" onClick = "document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = '200px'">Click Me!</button>
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ww1 = "";
var ww2 = 0;
var myVar1 ;
var myVar2 ;
function wm1(){
  myVar1 =setInterval(w1, 15);
}
function wm2(){
  myVar2 =setInterval(w2, 15);
}
function w1(){
 ww1=document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height;
 ww2= ww1.replace("px", ""); 
    if(parseFloat(ww2) <= 200){
document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = (parseFloat(ww2)+5) + 'px';
    }else{
      clearInterval(myVar1);
    }
}
function w2(){
 ww1=document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height;
 ww2= ww1.replace("px", ""); 
    if(parseFloat(ww2) >= 50){
document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = (parseFloat(ww2)-5) + 'px';
    }else{
      clearInterval(myVar2);
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>    
  </head>

<body >
    <button type="button" onClick = "wm1()">200px</button>
    <button type="button" onClick = "wm2()">50px</button>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color:#ccc"></div>
  
  <div id="demo"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the "px" in the style.height assignation, like:

```
<button type="button" onClick = "document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = 200px"> </button>
```

Should be

```
<button type="button" onClick = "document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.height = 200">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: That is incorrect, 'px' is required since the value is gonna be used in the stylesheet.